# java cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, drawstring, greenfoot

so i got this error:

```
java cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String,int,int; found:java.lang.String; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in lenghhs
```

when i typed this in one Actor (im using Greenfoot):

```
 public String getPunkte()
{
    String stringPunkte = Integer.toString(punkte);
    return(stringPunkte);
}
```

and this in the other:

```
public void malePunkte()
{
    GreenfootImage img = new GreenfootImage(50, 10);
    img.drawString(getPunkte());

}
```

for those who dont understand:
this is supposed to convert the int (punkte)(means points in german) into a String and then return the amount of points in one actor to the other, wich then displays that number.

if you still don't understand or  you need another piece of code just ask.

Thx

Comment: What is `punkte` in the first code snippet? Does `img.drawString` accept a `String`?

Comment: I'd guess that `drawString` takes two more parameters, the position where the string should appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well error is quite self explanatory isn't it ?

what you expect to get back is `String, int, int` and you only 'supply' `String`

try this

```
public void malePunkte() {
    GreenfootImage img = new GreenfootImage();
    img.drawString(getPunkte(), 50, 10);
}
```

ps. on return statement you do not need to surround with bracket the variable you want to return. Just do

```
return stringpunkte
```

ps. i have no idea what the GreenfootImage is ;)

edit: According to helpful link provided by - Gyro Gearless

www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/GreenfootImage.html

```
drawImage(GreenfootImage image, int x, int y) 
     Draws the given Image onto this image
```

and

```
GreenfootImage(int width, int height) 
      Create an empty (transparent) image with the specified size.
```

As you can see drawImage draws on top of the created 'empty' image. So as Constructor argument you can specify the size of empty image, and as  to a method you can specify the size of the new image that will go on top of the empty one

Comment: But there is no `GreenfootImage()` no-arg constructor! See http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/GreenfootImage.html

Comment: @GyroGearless yup that is true - well as i said i had no idea what the GreenfootImage is ;). I just looked at the error given. In that case OP has to figure out which constructor to use when creating new instance of this footImage.